# NSXMLParser and a xml with strange encoding

Tags: ios, xml, encoding, nsxmlparser

I can not parse an XML file

Originally, I declare my parser as:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"download.rss" withExtension:@"webintents"];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

when parsing, I encounter error

> NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 9

I check it's NSXMLParserInvalidCharacterError.

after the parser run through several tags and meet error at a tag.

Then I change the declaration to iterate the encoding as:

```
NSError *errorOfStr = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *xmlFeedStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"download.rss" withExtension:@"webintents"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&errorOfStr];

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[xmlFeedStr dataUsingEncoding:encoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
```

But I encounter error when initialing the variable "xmlFeedStr". Check "errorOfStr", I see the eror:

> Cocoa error 264

I check, it's  NSFileReadUnknownStringEncodingError

AFTER THAT, I tried to force some encoding as NSUTF8StringEncoding or NSUnicodeStringEncoding for the file, as below:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding;
NSString *xmlFeedStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"download.rss" withExtension:@"webintents"] encoding:encoding error:&error];
```

but no success. I met some Cocoa error as can not load file or load file with no content.

Please help me?

I put my file at:

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?yxfp3ch8n3ai4iq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem somewhere in the tag "content:encoded". Please use the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Application Did Finish Launching");

    NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/alex/Downloads/download.rss.webintents" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil] autorelease];

    NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Did Start Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"Found Characters: %@", string);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Found CDATA: %@", someString);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"Did End Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"Parser Did End Document");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"Parse Error Occurred: %@", parseError.description);   
}
```

Comment: I tried and it work. But can you explain the reason or any suggestion in you solution. You use 2 different encoding. So I can ensure that it work in later case. Because this xml file is update daily. I just encounter in some days, and some days not. Thank you